# Magento 2 does not load css or js after setup: upgrade

Tags: magento2, upgrade, mime-types

My website is in default mode only. After run "setup:upgrade" my web does not load the resources css or js. "Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

Any idea what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux then change the mode to `developer` and then run `php bin/magento cache:flush` from the document root of the webserver.

If you are using Windows then please follow the below steps:

1. change the mode to `developer`
2. run `php bin/magento cache:flush` from the project directory
3. run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` from the project directory

Please let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hi @bijeesh, I enabled to developer mode and try to flush the cache, it shows "There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace."

Comment: This happens if the the mysql/mariadb is down.

Comment: Please let me know how to clear this error?

Comment: You can restart mysql/mariadb, then the issue with "no commands defined in the X namespace" will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo su

cd /var/www/html/magento2
```

Set permissions to the files as follows

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Set permissions to the directories as follows

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Set permissions to special directories: as follows (these commands solve your file uploading issue)

```
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: Hi @praful, I tried above command and run "setup:upgrade" it shows, "sudo: bin/magento-cli: command not found".. still console shows same error.

Comment: can you share screenshots and did you have root access for cli

Answer (score 0):

Solution -

1. In file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf Navigate `<Directory /var/www/>`, Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" 2. Add this at last in env.php located at <MagentoRootDirectory/app/etc>

```html
`'system' => [
       'default' => [
           'web' => [
               'unsecure' => [
                   'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                   'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
               ],
               'secure' => [
                   'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                   'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
               ]
           ]
       ]
   ]`
```

2. In etc/di.xml, Search `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` Under that Modify this `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`
3. Add this in db `INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;`
4. Add this in db `UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '0' WHERE core_config_data.path LIKE '%web/seo/use_rewrites%';`
5. Run this command, `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Please check my edit - I have been taking guesses. Do the `\`` "backticks" belong in the snippet? In step 2., Search *what*?

Comment: Thanx @greybeard. That was a backtick mistake that disabled the code after search, I ahve edited it

Answer (score 0):

Please check the .htaccess file in pub/static/.htaccess. If not then please add it.

thanks!!